# How can I determine user and group in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I tried to Change the ownership to your development account and the goto the source directory.

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> ./freeradius_2.1.12+dfsg
```

But when user :root and group:root response from server is : invalid user

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You should make your question more clear and easier to understand, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the command is incorrect.  The correct syntax is:

```
sudo chown -R username:usergroup freeradius_2.1.12+dfsg
```

Both username and usergroup are missing in what you wrote.  So, if for example, you want **root** to be the owner, type:

```
sudo chown -R root:root freeradius_2.1.12+dfsg
```

Comment: i edit it but the problem still occur

Comment: The only thing I can think of then, is that maybe there are hidden characters or strange formatting in the username or groupname you are using and the system doesn't recognize them.  Are you typing the command or are you pasting it from somewhere?

Comment: i type the command